# Laravel 10 morphMany not retrieving notifiable models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need some assistance with my `morphMany` relationship. I'm building a feature around allowing a User to get various types of notifications through different notification channels. Here's my models:

- `NotificationNotifiable` - this defines the **id**, **notifiable_type**, **notifiable_id** and **notification_type_id** columns, this is the table that tracks all of the types that a user has enabled and want to receive notifications for.
- `NotificationChannel` - just a simple table defining the channel, e.g: push, email, SMS
- `NotificationType` - a table to define the types of notifications and their corresponding supported **notification_channel_id** column, maybe general marketing via email is a type.

> I've gone with `NotificationNotifiable` as I might have other models wishing to receive notifications too.

I'm able to retrieve data from my controller (notification preferences), but despite having an entry for a user I'm not seeing this under my `notificationNotifiable` relationship, it's empty, here's my models:

1. Model: `NotificationNotifiable`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class NotificationNotifiable extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'notification_notifiables';

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the parent notifiable model.
     */
    public function notifiable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification type for this model.
     */
    public function notificationType(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(NotificationType::class);
    }
}
```

2. Model: `NotificationChannel`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class NotificationChannel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'notification_channels';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'display_order' => 'integer',
        'requires_subscription' => 'boolean',
        'is_popular' => 'boolean',
        'is_recommended' => 'boolean',
        'is_enabled' => 'boolean',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the notification types for this model.
     */
    public function notificationTypes(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(NotificationType::class);
    }
}
```

3. Model: `NotificationType`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class NotificationType extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'notification_types';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'display_order' => 'integer',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'has_notifiables'
    ];

    /**
     * Determine whether the notification type has notifiables
     */
    public function getHasNotifiablesAttribute(): bool
    {
        if (isset($this->notificationNotifiables) && count($this->notificationNotifiables) > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification channels for this model
     */
    public function notificationChannels(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(NotificationChannel::class, 'notification_channel_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the model's notifiables
     */
    public function notificationNotifiables(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(NotificationNotifiable::class, 'notifiable');
    }
}
```

Here's my `/account/1/notification-preferences` endpoint index function:

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 */
public function index(User $account, Request $request)
{
    try {
        $channels = NotificationChannel::withWhereHas('notificationTypes', function ($query) {
            $query->with([
                'notificationNotifiables' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('notifiable_type', User::class)->where('notifiable_id', Auth::id());
                }
            ])->orderBy('display_order', 'asc');
        })->orderBy('display_order', 'asc')->get();

        if (! $channels || count($channels) <= 0) {
            return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
                'message' => 'No channels found.',
            ], 404);
        }

        return new ApiSuccessResponse($channels);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
            'message' => 'Unable to load channels, please try again soon.',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Why would `notificationNotifiables` by empty despite there being an entry in this table?

[image: notifiables database]

[image: empty relationship]

Comment: Couple of clarifications, is `Auth::id()` containing the desired `id`? Also can there be multiple `NotificationType` for `notificationChannels` and `notificationNotifiables` (if not consider renaming it for better readability remove the plural)? And lastly did you try using `with` instead of `withWhereHas`?

Comment: Switched out to `hasMany`, thanks.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77441098/timeline) attracted at least one [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.